# XAMPP Virtual Hosts not working on Windows 10

Tags: apache, xampp, windows-10

***Before marking this as answered, please read the entire thing because yes there is a good amount of these questions but NONE of the answers on them have worked at all.***

Hosts File

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       abv
```

httpd.conf

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

index.php

```
echo "abc";
```

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/xampp/htdocs/abv"
    ServerName abv
    ErrorLog "abv-error.log"
    CustomLog "abv-access.log" common
    <Directory "/xampp/htdocs/abv">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all    
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Access LOG

```
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jul/2019:10:09:50 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jul/2019:10:09:50 +0530] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 1053
```

These Setting are running perfectly and output is showing and now replacing with below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "F:\Websites\abv"
    ServerName abv
    ErrorLog "abv-error.log"
    CustomLog "abv-access.log" common
    <Directory "F:\Websites\abv">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all    
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Access LOG

```
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jul/2019:10:09:57 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 384
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jul/2019:10:09:57 +0530] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 1053
```

No out is showing WHY?

Comment: In your original logs, it says `200 3`.  In the second, it ways `200 384`.  That number next to 200 is the size of the response.  Test with the same file first, then change the file.  If you see nothing it is probably in the content that there is something wrong.  Do a view source in the browser to ensure you got what you expected.  Post here if it still does not help figure it out.

Comment: And your index.php should be `<?php echo "abc"; ?>` right?